# How to incorporate an "animated border and glow effect" code to a picture animation (html/css)

Tags: html, css

I found a really cool animation of codepen and i really want to incorperate the border glow effect to the picture animation.

Codepen css code:

```css
@property --rotate {
    syntax: "<angle>";
    initial-value: 132deg;
    inherits: false;
}

:root {
    --card-height: 65vh;
    --card-width: calc(var(--card-height) / 1.5);
}

body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #212534;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-top: 2rem;
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card {
    background: #191c29;
    width: var(--card-width);
    height: var(--card-height);
    padding: 3px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 6px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: rgb(88 199 250 / 0%);
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: cursive;
}

.card:hover {
    color: rgb(88 199 250 / 100%);
    transition: color 1s;
}

.card:hover:before,
.card:hover:after {
    animation: none;
    opacity: 0;
}

.card::before {
    content: "";
    width: 104%;
    height: 102%;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(var(--rotate), #5ddcff, #3c67e3 43%, #4e00c2);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: -1%;
    left: -2%;
    animation: spin 2.5s linear infinite;
}

.card::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: calc(var(--card-height) / 6);
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    transform: scale(0.8);
    filter: blur(calc(var(--card-height) / 6));
    background-image: linear-gradient(var(--rotate), #5ddcff, #3c67e3 43%, #4e00c2);
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
    animation: spin 2.5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% {
        --rotate: 0deg;
    }
    100% {
        --rotate: 360deg;
    }
}

a {
    color: #212534;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 2rem;
}
```

My code html:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Creative Menu Effect</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="2ndpage.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="logoWrapper">
            <img class="logo" src="Images/Untitled.png" alt="logo">
            <a class="mtap">
                Mount <br> Apo
            </a>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav_links">
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <a class="cta" href="#"><button>Contact</button></a>
    </header>

    <section class="container">
        <div class="clip clip1"></div>
        <div class="clip clip2"></div>
        <div class="clip clip3"></div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

my code css:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap');

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #24252A;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

li, a, button {
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #edf0f1;
    text-decoration: none;
}

header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 30px 10%;
}

.logo {
    width: 100px;
}

.logoWrapper {
    display: flex;
    gap: 10px;
    align-items: center;
}

.mtap {
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #edf0f1;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.mtap:hover {
    color: #0088a9;
}

.nav_links {
    list-style: none;
}

.nav_links li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

.nav_links li a {
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}

.nav_links li a:hover {
    color: #0088a9;
}

button {
    padding: 9px 25px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 136, 169, 1);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 136, 169, 0.8);
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}

ul {
    display: flex;
}

ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0.4rem 1rem;
    margin: 0 10px;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav_links li a:before {
    content: "";
    position: relative;
    bottom: 12px;
    left: 12px;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border: 3px solid white;
    border-width: 0 0 3px 3px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.6s;
}

.nav_links li a:hover:before {
    opacity: 1;
    bottom: -8px;
    left: -8px;
}

.nav_links li a:after {
    content: "";
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border: 3px solid
}
```

ive done trying too change the value of "card" to container and it doesnt work, im still new at coding so im sorry if there is a lack of information! :)

Comment: You mention that you want to add that affect to a picture animation. However, your code doesn't have any picture animations in it.

Comment: Use the `<>` button to create a runnable snippet out of your code. You should make an attempt to solve it yourself first.